Perpendicular intersection of complex hypersurfaces
Let $(X,\omega)$ be a Kaehler manifold and $D_1,D_2$ a pair of compact smooth divisors in $X$ which intersect transversely, i.e. $D_1$ and $D_2$ are codimension 1 complex submanifolds of $X$ and for $x\in D_1\cap D_2$ we have $T_xX=T_xD_1+T_xD_2$.
I am wondering if there is a Kaehler metric in the Kaehler class of $\omega$ for which $D_1$ and $D_2$ intersect perpendicularly, i.e. the line bundles $Ann(TD_1),Ann(TD_2)\subset T^*X\vert_{D_1\cap D_2}$ are orthogonal subspaces?
When $X$ is a surface, this is true by the following argument. The intersection $D_1\cap D_2$ is a collection of isolated points, and there are local coordinates near $x\in D_1\cap D_2$ for which $D_1=\{x_1=0\}$ and $D_2=\{x_2=0\}$. A mild strengthening of a result of Demailly (cf: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609617 section 4) tells us that given a germ of a Kaehler metrics $\omega'\in \Omega^{1,1}(X)_{D_1\cap D_2}$ there is a Kahler metric $\tilde{\omega}\in \Omega^{1,1}(X)$ in the Kaehler class of $\omega$ restricting to $\omega'$. As such we can take the germ of the standard Kaehler form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and pull it back via our coordinates to yield a form with $D_1\perp D_2$.
In general, I believe one has the following theorem:
Let $B\subset X$ be a compact analytic subset of $(X,\omega)$ a Kahler manifold. If $\omega'\in \Omega^{1,1}(X)_{B}$ is a germ of a Kaehler metric (i.e. an equivalence class of Kaehler metrics on open neighborhoods of $B$) with $[\omega'\vert_{U}]=[\omega\vert_{U}]$ on some $U\supset B$ an open neighborhood, there exists a global $\tilde{\omega}\in \Omega^{1,1}(X)$ Kaehler, with $\tilde{\omega}\vert_{V}=\omega'\vert_{V}$ for $V\subset U$ a neighborhood of $B$, with $[\tilde{\omega}]=[\omega]$.
Using this result, we can reduce the problem to a germ problem. I am now left wondering if there is some obstruction to finding germs of Kaehler forms on $D_1\cap D_2$ making $D_1$ and $D_2$ orthogonal?
(Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/482028/perpendicular-intersection-of-complex-hypersurfaces)
